# Yii2:Date Application Formatter

Tags: php, datetime, yii2

I am using `Yii::$app->formatter` in one of my attribute like:

**Controller code**

```
$model->discharge_date=Yii::$app->formatter->asDatetime
($model->discharge_date, 'php:d-M-Y H:i');
```

**Model Code**

```
[['admission_date','discharge_date'],'date','format' => 'php:d-M-Y H:i'],
```

Everything is working fine except when discharge date is left blank, on update it is filled with this line:

`<span class="not-set">(not set)</span>`

I couldn't make out from where this is coming, as in the DB the value is `NUll`

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's default and expected behavior.

See documentation for [$nullDisplay](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-formatter.html#$nullDisplay-detail) property of [Formatter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-formatter.html).

You can cnahge that across application through application configuration:

```
'formatter' => [
    'nullDisplay' => '',
],
```

For specific view you can change it through formatter component (note that you should add that code before view is rendered):

```
use Yii;

...

Yii::$app->formatter->nullDisplay = '';
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Actually I have also tried the same like `nullDispaly =>Null` but it didn't worked.